# why is the radom number generation not right?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, random

Below is my code:

```
uniform_int_distribution<>temp(-1,1);
default_random_engine e((unsigned int)time(0));
for(int a=0;a<50;a++){
cout<<temp(e)<<endl;
}
```

You know, I expect the number range is -1,0,1 ,these three numbers.
    Actually the result normally only contains 0 and 1.
    If I run this program several times, then, seldom the -1 number will be last number of one time.
    I don't know why, uniform_int_distribution should contains -1, right?

Comment: [I get different results](http://ideone.com/x79PU), perhaps you specify what compiler and the full code you used. `default_random_engine` uses an implementation defined engine.

Comment: I also get different result. Quite uniform. Try the following:   http://pastebin.com/gbL9j8Zx

Comment: paddy gives answer below, it is a bug of VS. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug that has apparently been fixed: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/712984

If you need a workaround right now without installing software updates, why not just generate between 0 and 2, then subtract 1 afterwards?

Comment: Oh, I'm totally assuming you're using Visual Studio.  Apologies if I'm incorrect.

Comment: Oh, You are right , I am using Visual studio. Thanks a lot, this is just a bug, great :)

Comment: What a catch! how do fast, succinct, and undoubtedly correct answers like this go un-voted? +1.

Comment: @Ben "There is no charge for awesomeness" -- Kung Fu Panda